# Language based settings in VS Code do not work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am trying to add language based settings for several languages. In order to do so, I modified the file `settings.json` (see [Configure language based settings in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_language-specific-editor-settings) for more information) as follows:

```
{
    "editor.tabSize": 4,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.formatOnSave": true,
    "vsicons.dontShowNewVersionMessage": false,
    "[dart]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    "[typescript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },
    "[c]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    }
}
```

As you can see, I have the tab size option set to 2 for Dart and to 4 for other languages. The default value for indentation is 4 and `"editor.detectIndentation"` is disabled. But for some reason the editor doesn't get these settings:
[image: Screenshot of the code snippet written in Dart]
For this reason, `IndentRainbow` extension does not work properly. On the bar below you can see that VS code still has "4" for tab size.

If I change the global setting for the tab size (`editor.tabSize`), VS Code just set the new value, e.g., 2 and I have then in all files and for all languages this value for indentation. I also tried to restart VS Code after settings were changed, it didn't help. What can I do to make what I want work properly?

`settings.json` is saved in `C:\Users\MyName\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\`

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I can see that 3+ years have passed since you posted your question and "solution", but I don't have the EditorConfig extension installed. I considered installing it to work around this problem.

Comment: @Vince Did you finally solve the problem without the extension? If so, feel free to write an answer, I'll mark it as the "accepted answer".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out for myself what the problem was. Under the extensions tab, I have the [EditorConfig](https://editorconfig.org/) extension. This extension always overrides the user and workspace settings. I simply disabled this extension.

Another possible solution would be to create an `.editorconfig` file in the folder in which the project is located and to specify there the tab size.

Comment: Had the issue mentioned in the title, didn't have the EditorConfig extension installed, but I disabled a bunch of extensions I wasn't using anyway and it solved the problem for me. Thank you!